# awareness of or awareness for something?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

This program was initiated to increase the awareness for breast cancer. 
does this seem correct? or the preposition 'for' be replaced with 'of'?

Comment: What [research](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/awareness) have you already done?

Answer (score 1):

I did not find any examples with `for`, but I did find `of` and `about`

`The campaign aims to raise awareness of the dangers of passive smoking.`

`There was a general lack of awareness about safety issues.`

Answer (score -1):

This strikes me as one of the common ambiguities of current use of English, that of distinction between possessive preposition, and using 'for' as a conjunctive prep. One implies the individual awareness, one demonstrating the purpose of the group cited.
Both are worthy, and all strength to those who sing either.